# Using variadic macro arguments as a list

Tags: clojure, macros, variadic-macros

I was trying to write a macro that compares the running times of multiple expressions, and ran into a wall. My problem can be condensed to the following code:

```
(defmacro test-m [& exprs]
  `(map #(.toString %) ~exprs))
```

If I call this like `(test-m 1 2 3)`, I would expect this to produce code along the lines of:

```
(map #(.toString %) [1 2 3])
```

Which is entirely valid. Unfortunately though, this actually results in an error:

> ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn  helpers.general-helpers/eval663 (NO_SOURCE_FILE:76)

The only way I could see this possibly happening is if `& exprs` results in `(1 2 3)`, which would then attempt to call `1` as a function, which is obviously wrong.

How can I map over a variadic argument list in a macro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out while writing the question, so I thought I'd post an answer in case anyone else is stuck here in the future.

The argument list needs to forced into a list representatiom first, or else it will be evaluated as a form. This can be done like:

```
(defmacro test-m [& exprs]
  `(map #(.toString %) (list ~@exprs))
```

Note the `exprs` are expanded via `@`, and given to `list`. (Thanks @amalloy for the correction).

Obvious is retrospect, but it held me up for a while. Hopefully this helps someone.

Comment: You probably don't want to quote it, but rather write `(list ~@exprs)` or `~(vec exprs)`.

Comment: @amalloy What's the difference in the end? Quoting it seems more straight forward. I'm not trying to be argumentative; I'm legitimately curious.

Comment: Try it with x y z variables instead of 1 2 3 constants.

Comment: @amalloy Whoops! Thanks. Good catch.